# Why does date() not convert YYMMDDHHMM to MySQL acceptable date format correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I would like to take a string like:

```
1511030830 // YYMMDDHHMM
```

And create a MySQL timestamp like:

```
2015-11-03 08:30:00
```

However when try this it will not work:

```
$string='1511030830';
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $string);
var_dump($date);exit;
```

Because the above outputs:

```
string(19) "1970-01-01 02:00:00"
```

I am using PHP version 5.5.30

Is there some kind of settings in php.ini that would affect this?

Comment: [It's working fine for me](https://eval.in/461933)

Comment: it will not work?? what isssue you r getting??

Comment: @Uchiha its working fine for me also. ouptup `string(19) "2017-11-19 00:17:10" `

Comment: working for me too..!!

Comment: @Uchiha Can you see my update? Any idea why I would be getting this result then?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju See my update please, any advice?

Comment: @Suyog See my update please, any advice?

Comment: I see, I get `2017-11-18 19:47:10` when I run your code.

Comment: Are you getting any error. As your code works fine for us or post your original code over here

Comment: what is the problem, you are getting the expected Output. what do you want?

Comment: @CyberBoy How is my output expected when everyone says it works but for me it does not?

Comment: [There is no version issues over here](https://3v4l.org/0gkBU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateTime::createFromFormat:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHi', '1511030830');
var_dump($date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

That should do what you need.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Its giving empty result, just check once.

Comment: I was only setting the $date var, even in the example, OP asked to have this: `1511030830` string, in the format: `YYMMDDHHMM` to be parsed as the date, not as a unix timestamp, therefor, any result with year 2017 is incorrect

Comment: Trying this out on another system, this is actually better as it reports the correct hours, minutes and seconds without any adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `DateTime` class of PHP like as

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("ydmhi","1511030830");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/461987)

Comment: I've already used that but can't specify why OP is getting such value @NiranjanNRaju

Comment: In your demo the time does not reflect 8:30:00 am? How to set this so it is exact?

Comment: Whats your timezone. @IndigoIdentity

Comment: Africa/Johannesburg - setting it to like UTC doesn't solve the issue with hours, mins, secs?

Comment: @Uchiha: You assumed that `1511030830` was a unix timestamp, but it is a string formatted as "YYMMDDHHMM", so your answer (as are most of the answers here) is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `str_to_date`

```
SELECT str_to_date(1511030830,'%y%d%m')
```

Comment: Need to do it in PHP, do not have MySQL functions available at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your `php version` once. My current version in server `5.5.18` and in local `5.6.11`

Im using your code only. Its working fine

```
$string='1511030830';
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $string);
var_dump($date);exit;
```

Output:

```
string(19) "2017-11-18 10:47:10"
```

See demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/690ace92d4897dffc2802e3a0170d68615fb13e2)

```
$timestamp = 1511030830;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);//2017-11-18 18:47:10
```

Demo for `gmdate()` [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12d2706ae547fbad9c8a92bed76fe36772624a42)

Comment: But it's not working for me in php 5.5, any idea why? Something in php.ini that affects this?

Comment: Real version: PHP 5.5.30-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Comment: `echo phpversion();` see what is your version.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity you need to post your original code else your code is working fine for us

Comment: Even if `1511030830` it outputs `2017-11-18 10:47:10`, it is still not what the OP wanted. the `$string` is being interpeted as a unix timestamp, not a `YYMMDDHHMM` representative of a date `2015-11-03 08:30:00`

Comment: @Uchiha Bud, that is the original code, it will not work for me. Going to update my question to reflect troubleshooting.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity se the updated answer, i have used `gmdate()`

Comment: gmdate works o.O really scratching my head here... Thank you though!

Comment: Oh , I see, it is returning the wrong Date and Time.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity 
 
getting expected result??

Comment: There is still a problem here, look at the conversion for minutes and seconds. In my example it should be 08:30:00 (am) but in this it gives " 20:47:10", changing to small `h` works to make it am but the minutes and seconds are still wrong?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I have no idea why but gmdate() is working somewhat.

Comment: just set your time zone and try once.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");`

Comment: Not solving the issue to set the default timezone, still have problem with hours, minutes and seconds but this is now `03:47:10`?

Comment: It is also year 2017 instead of 2015

Comment: @Werring Lol *bows* you're a champ man thank you, makes almost perfect sense to me now! :)

Comment: Be careful, your example is working with a teimestamp, not with a string composed of a concatenated date !