# Change date time to UTC FORMAT

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework

I need to rewrite date time format from zendframework to codeigniter

Here is Zendframe work UTC format function

```
function _dayToDateTime($day, $begin = true)
{
    $oDate = new Date($day);
    if (!$begin) {
        $oDate->setHour(23);
        $oDate->setMinute(59);
        $oDate->setSecond(59);
    }
    $oDate->toUTC();

    return $oDate->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
}
```

Here is my code for codeigniter

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$dt = new DateTime($from_date,$timeZone);
$dt->setTime(23, 59, 59);
echo $format=$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But I didn't get same date result.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your default time zone as `UTC`

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

You can also use `gmdate`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492868/why-does-date-not-convert-yymmddhhmm-to-mysql-acceptable-date-format-correctly/33492940#33492940) for more reference.